# Error in printing invoice from admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, print

I'm facing an error when I try to print new order invoice, error details are given below,

> There has been an error processing your request

Image is not a PNG:

```
Trace:
#0 /home/.../public_html/lib/Zend/Pdf/Resource/ImageFactory.php(54): Zend_Pdf_Resource_Image_Png->__construct('/home/orangesna...')
#1 /home/.../public_html/lib/Zend/Pdf/Image.php(124): Zend_Pdf_Resource_ImageFactory::factory('/home/orangesna...')
#2 /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php(158): Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath('/home/orangesna...')
#3 /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php(123): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract->insertLogo(Object(Zend_Pdf_Page), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Store))
#4 /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php(119): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice->getPdf(Array)
#5 /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php(489): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice->printAction()
#6 /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController->printAction()
#7 /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('print')
#8 /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /home/.../public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /home/.../public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}

Error log record number: 887679800526
```

Answer (score 1):

> Image is not a PNG

Logo for PDF Print-outs was uploaded with "png" file extension, but actual type differs. So image factory tries to handle it as png, but fails.
Reupload of the new image with correct format will fix this issue.

Comment: My issue is, image name is with .png extension but the logo file is not in PNG format.